# adding buttons to slidedown tab using jquery

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<div class="sign-up-wrapper">

<div class="sign-up-container">
<div id="sign-up-myButton" class="sign-up-header"></div>
<div id="sign-up-content" class="hide-content">content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here</div>
</div>
<div id="sign-up-myButton3" class="sign-up-footer">Button 1</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
body {padding:0;margin:0;}

.sign-up-wrapper {border:1px solid red;width:459px;line-height:normal;font-size:18px;z-index:110;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;}
.sign-up-container {}
.sign-up-header {height:8px;}
.hide-content {position: absolute !important;top: -9999px !important;left: -9999px !important;}

.sign-up-footer {text-align:center;width:99px;height:23px;cursor:pointer;background:#999;margin-left:19px;}


#sign-up-content {background:#096;width:420px;margin:auto;}
```

jQuery

```
var $button = jQuery('#sign-up-myButton3'),
  $text   = jQuery('#sign-up-content'),
  visible = false;

$button.click(function(){
if ( visible ) {
  $text.slideUp('fast',function(){
    $text.addClass('hide-content')
         .slideDown(0);
  });
} else {
  $text.slideUp(0,function(){
    $text.removeClass('hide-content')
         .slideDown('fast');
  });
}
visible = ! visible;
});
```

can please help me, how can I add 2 or 3 buttons beside button 1 with different contents in every button when pressed

I only got 1 button with content, here is My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gbFKe/

Comment: not really clear - you want tabs?..

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan is this what you looking for: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ `:)` can make a fiddle for you otherwise the link has simple implementation.

Comment: actually, I like to have a dropdown slide tab that displays the content when clicked, like what I have on fiddle, but I need 3 tabs that slides down also with content

Answer (score 0):

fildler solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gbFKe/1/)
html

```
    <div class="sign-up-wrapper">
<div id="sign-up-myButton1" class="sign-up-footer">Button 1</div>
<div id="sign-up-myButton2" class="sign-up-footer">Button 2</div>
<div id="sign-up-myButton3" class="sign-up-footer">Button 3</div>
<div class="sign-up-container">
<div id="sign-up-myButton" class="sign-up-header"></div>
<div id="sign-up-content1" class="hide-content">content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here content here</div>
    <div id="sign-up-content2" class="hide-content">button2 content</div>
    <div id="sign-up-content3" class="hide-content">button3content</div>
</div>
</div>​
```

jquery , having redundant code you can customize according to your need

```
    var $button1 = jQuery('#sign-up-myButton1'),
      $text1   = jQuery('#sign-up-content1'),
      visible = false;

    $button1.click(function(){
    if ( visible ) {
      $text1.slideUp('fast',function(){
        $text1.addClass('hide-content')
             .slideDown(0);
      });
    } else {
      $text1.slideUp(0,function(){
        $text1.removeClass('hide-content')
             .slideDown('fast');
      });
    }
    visible = ! visible;
    });
var $button2 = jQuery('#sign-up-myButton2'),
      $text2   = jQuery('#sign-up-content2'),
      visible = false;

    $button2.click(function(){
    if ( visible ) {
      $text2.slideUp('fast',function(){
        $text2.addClass('hide-content')
             .slideDown(0);
      });
    } else {
      $text2.slideUp(0,function(){
        $text2.removeClass('hide-content')
             .slideDown('fast');
      });
    }
    visible = ! visible;
    });


var $button3 = jQuery('#sign-up-myButton3'),
      $text3   = jQuery('#sign-up-content3'),
      visible = false;

    $button3.click(function(){
    if ( visible ) {
      $text3.slideUp('fast',function(){
        $text3.addClass('hide-content')
             .slideDown(0);
      });
    } else {
      $text3.slideUp(0,function(){
        $text3.removeClass('hide-content')
             .slideDown('fast');
      });
    }
    visible = ! visible;
    });

​
```

Comment: and what if he wants to have 20 tabs?.. 20 times repeat the same code?

Comment: I only want 3 or 4 tabs on it that slides down when clicked, I mean the tab slides down with its content like in My fiddle

Comment: you need not to repead the code , you may refactor it ,and i think you are experience enough to refactor it ,if not please let me know to provide you a generic code,which will work for N number of tabs

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the basic idea of what you should do.

Javascript

```
$('#content').hide();
$('#content2').hide();
$('#content3').hide();

$('#button1').on('click',function(){
    $('#content').slideDown();
});​​​​​​​​

$('#button2').on('click',function(){
    $('#content2').slideDown();
});   

$('#button3').on('click',function(){
    $('#content3').slideDown();
});
```

​
HTML

```
    <button id='button1'>Button1</button>
    <div id='content'>
        <p>Test</p>
        <button id='button2'>Button1</button>
        <button id='button3'>Button1</button>
        <div id='content2'>
            <p>alsdkfjasdfl</p>
        </div>
        <div id='content3'>
            <p>asdfladsf</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```